# How much should you deposit to accomplish this financial objective?

Tags: dynamical-systems, finance, mathematical-modeling

You plan to invest a part of your paycheck(a fixed monthly investment) to finance your children's higher education. You want to have $\$1,000,000$ accumulated in the account at the end of $20$ years from now. If the account pays $0.5\%$ interest each month, how much should you deposit each month during next $20$ years to accomplish this financial objective?

Let $x_n$ be the money after $n$ months and $x_0=0$

$p$ be money deposit each month

$x_{n+1}=(x_n+p)0.005+x_n+p=1.005x_n+1.005p$

by solving this I obtained $x_n=(201p)(1.005)^n-201p$

After $20$ years,
$$1000000=(201p)(1.005)^{240}-201p$$

then $p=2153.54$

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: At the end of the first month you have an amount of $x_1=p$. The payments are made at the end of the month. Then $x_2=x_1\cdot 1.005+p=p\cdot 1.005+p$ and so on.

Comment: @callculus As I think it is same as what I did

Comment: Not really. In your case $x_1=1.005p$

Comment: @callculus Why didn't you add interest to first month?

Comment: I thought the payments are made at the made at the **end** of each month. But it is not clear from the exercise. If the payments are made at the **beginning** of each month then you´re right ($\checkmark$).

Comment: I would probably argue that the paycheck is made at the end of each month and you invest the payment p immediately.

Comment: @callculus I think you are correct I thought it would be beginning of each month

Comment: It is a matter of interpretation. Nevertheless,  your approach is right.

Comment: @callculus Thank you  very much

Comment: You´re welcome.